# How do I install ISO file in Ubuntu virtualbox with 64 bit?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, iso

How do I install ISO file in Ubuntu **virtualbox** with **64 bit**? I have the ISO file yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

You go to Settings -> Storage
Under Controller IDE, click on Host Drive.

On the right where it says Attributes -> CD/DVD Drive, Click on the cd image, and select 'choose a virtual CD/DVD disk file. Proceed to the File Browser and find the location of your iso file. Once you click open, the iso file will become your virtual CD/DVD drive, and you can install Yosemite from the iso file that way.

Comment: This does not answer the original question which was about installing OS X in VirtualBox running in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @karel it basically does. Just replace "Ubuntu" with "Yosemite" (as I just did) and the same answer applies.

Comment: Even after replacing "Ubuntu" with "Yosemite" this answer still wouldn't work because installing OS X in VirtualBox requires some additional modifications in VBoxManage specific to OS X Yosemite, and I don't have a copy of OS X Yosemite to test it, so I can't fix this answer by editing it.

Comment: @karel ah, OK, fair enough. It's still an answer though. Just a wrong or incomplete one then.